# CSS - HTML How to get the anchor image to a specific side

Tags: html, css

I want all of the anchor images in different corners , eg , top left , top right , bottom right , bottom right , and one in the centre thank you

How do I make all my anchor links / images go to specific sides I want the teams one on top left I want store top right sponsors bottom left and about us bottom right I thought I did all the right code but they don't how up in those specific spots

If anyone can help it will be greatly appreciates

**CSS**

```css
.icon1.jpg {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      height: auto;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .icon2.jpg {
      position: relative;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      height: auto;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .icon4.jpg {
      position: relative;
      left: 0px;
      height: auto;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .icon3.jpg {
      position: relative;
      right: 0px;
      height: auto;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .DelUZens {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    body {
      background: url("icon6.jpg") repeat;
    }
    #banner {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 175px;
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>DelUZens</title>
  <link href="main.css" rel="stlesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000">
    <div z-index:1;>
      <p>
        <a href="teams.html" target="_blank">
          <img src="icon1.jpg" style='width:50%;' border="0" alt="Null" class="top" z-index:2>
        </a>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="store.html" target="_blank">
          <img src="icon2.jpg" style='width:50%;' border="0" alt="Null" class="right" z-index:3>

        </a>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="sponsors.html" target="_blank">
          <img src="icon4.jpg" style='width:50%;' border="0" alt="Null" class="left" z-index:4>
        </a>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="aboutus.html" target="_blank">
          <img src="icon3.jpg" style='width:50%;' border="0" alt="Null" class="bottom" z-index:5>
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="myDiv" style="position:absolute; top:230px; left:591px; right: 591px; bottom: 230px;  width:0px; height:0px; z-index:8;">
      <img src="icon5.png" class="DelUZens">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are many issues, invalid html, css that is not targeting anything...

Comment: You should learn css and css class first. Where is class like `.icon2.jpg` and other?

Answer (score 0):

I would **NEVER** personally layout a page this way, however it will fix your problem with the current layout, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5pre17op/1/

Note: this `.icon1.jpg` is targeting a class called `icon` and `jpg` either of these classes do not exist in your page, however you do have classes named `top` `left` `right` and `bottom`, you need to target them like this:

```
.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to refer to each image by using their class name but not src of image, e.g. for the first link:

CSS

```
 .top {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   height: auto;
   width: 50%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have relative wrapper and in this holder put anchors.

```
<div class="section-links">
```

See [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/rs9Lqjaq/)

Answer (score -1):

```
.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.DelUZens {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
body {
  background: url("icon6.jpg") repeat;
}
#banner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 175px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Use position absolute instead of relative.